# Share NSUserDefaults in universal binary between iPhone and iPad Versions

Tags: iphone, ipad, nsuserdefaults, universal-binary

This is my first stab at creating two targets within one project for iPhone and iPad.

My question is, if I save an array to NSUserDefaults, and the iPhone syncs with iTunes, and then I sync the iPad, will the iPad version have access to the array synced to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While iTunes backs up defaults, it doesn't push them back to the device — there are only a handful of things that it syncs (music/etc, contacts, calendar, ...).

It's also unclear how you want to keep things in sync. Let's say you change the default on both devices, and then sync both of them. What happens?

If you're feeling *particularly* perverse, you can encode the default into a specially-named contact (and there's a "take me home" app that stores the "home" location in a specially-named contact, IIRC). Presumably this results in an edit conflict; I think iTunes tells the user this and lets them fix the problem by deciding which version to keep.

But I really wouldn't want to rely on iTunes syncing. I go for months without syncing (or waiting long enough for iTunes to make a backup — annoying when the phone bricks itself).

Answer (score 3):

You either have a *universal binary* or you have *two different targets*.

As syncing is concerned, I think it syncs each device differently - even two iPhones should get separate defaults.